# How can I get stdin of any sort to work with emscripten?

Tags: c, emscripten

I have been trying to use emscripten.  However, trying to get any input in `node` makes it puke (or ignore input entirely.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

int main(void){
    //fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    int number;
    printf("Please enter a number.\n");
    scanf("%i", &number);
    printf("This is a compile test for emscript.  \n By the way, your number was: %i",i);
 }
```

I have looked at this [link](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/3904), this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/_AwjqEzYZmE) (some of that is clearly obsolete) and a number of example files that are meant to be used with `--pre-js`.  NOTHING seems to work.

I'm starting to think I'm an idiot because a google search for "emscripten scanf" for the *last year* reveals nothing but less than a page of utterly useless results, so I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious.

Regardless, the only results I can get include: `node` hangs when you use scanf, node ignores scanf, or node lets you hit enter an infinite number of times before scanf works.

Googling "emscripten stdin" is slighty more fruitful, providing [this](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/issues/1060) with the "recommended" way to ..... aww, who am I kidding.  (But I hope I've proved I put some real effort into this before giving up and asking.)

Thanks in advance.
(PS: When using the html version, this seems to mirror the node behavior, looping dialog box and all.)

**Edit:** This example sort of works in the web browser - it gives me the prompt screen and otherwise seems to work pretty normally (but the prompt loops over and over.)

Comment: `printf("This is a compile test for emscript.  \n By the way, your number was:");` did you forget to print the number ?

Comment: @Stargateur Ever seen that Captain picard facepalm thing?  (That does not change the results for `node` in the console; it does for the HTML version.)